# Not able to save a word file

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have an app that builds a word document file from a data-set with Merge fields.

Everything worked fine, but the program won't run on our terminal server.
However, it works fine on my local machine.

I am getting the error `"Command failed"` on my terminal server. My code runs, but I'm not able to save the document afterwords.

```
word.AddTemplate(strFQDN, ref objDoc, ref objWord);
word.ParagraphsInList(ref objDoc, ref objWord, ref parags);
word.PrintParagraphsPerRecord(ref objWord, ref objDoc, ref parags, ds, PKref);
word.WordInvullen(ref objDoc, ref objWord, PKref, ds);
```

All the above with the subcode work. When I come to the saving part I get the command failed.

```
//objWord.Documents.Save(ref missing, ref missing);
//objWord.Documents.Save(false, true);
//objDoc.Save();
objDoc.SaveAs2("c:\\Template\\offerte 1001", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Does anyone have a clue why the saving part of the `word.interop` isn't working?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? Try running it as admin. Also might be nothing but get rid of the spaces in the doc name.

Comment: to use office interop, office has to be installed on the pc. usually applicationservers dont have office installed. try take a look at docx format or use aspose.

Comment: @Prahalad Please!!! not!!! so!!! much!!! exclamation marks!!!

Comment: It can't be auto save with interop. there's no problem with your code. What i suggest you is using openxml (if you want to save your document in 2007 format) Enjoy Coding!

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: Yes, i am in the administrators group.

Comment: Yes but are you running the program as admin?

Comment: solved.
The problem was file block settings on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently this was the problem:

[image]

The save was disabled in the file block settings.